# Filter data with more than date ranges in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i need to filter some data from multiple date ranges

Say

```
public class ProductSale{
 public long ID {get; set;}
 public long ProductID {get; set;}
 public DateTime SaleDate {get; set;}
 ...
}
public class ProductSaleRang{
 public long ID {get; set;}
 public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
 public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
 ...
```

}

i have these two tables
above as product sale records and second has sale range dates for reporting 
i need to know count of every product sale count combine in all the ranges mention in  ProductSaleRange Table(two ranges never be overlapping to each other)
how do i achieve this in LINQ.
need help
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please give an example to clarify? example table data and requested result data would be great.

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ is just the API, not the ORM. Are you using Entity Framework? Did you try something? Did you encounter a problem? Can you please rephrase the question, providing examples of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest one from code readebility. Anyway it has complexity O(n*m) and I don't know if it fits your needs.

```
List<ProductSale> productSales = /*Data here*/;
List<ProductSaleRang> productSaleRang = /*data here*/ ;

productSales.Where(ps => productSaleRang.Any(psr => psr.StartDate <= ps.SaleDate && psr.EndDate >= ps.SaleDate));
```